# Weback and separate files

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I want to separate my vue.js application into some files that knows each other and don't want to require any required instance again. For example My first chunk has Vue.js instance and last chunk want to use it. How can I use webpack to this?

Comment: Please be more specific and explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: @gurghet I used all wepack solutions like expose that make global my dependency. But it isn't current way. I have dependency on this file too. I think it follows that I move it to Browserify with factory-bundle solution.